# Website SSL certificate error only for a handful of government customers

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, magento-2.3

We recently switched from a Comodo SSL certificate to a LetsEncrypt certificate. Since then (about 2 weeks) a handful of government users that buy from our website have encountered an error stating the certificate is invalid and their browser refuses to let them bypass the warning/error. We have received a few different error screenshots from our customers. Most said invalid SSL certificate, others mentioned an HSTS configuration error.

I am able to view our website and our (valid) LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on multiple public networks and from a VPN on the other side of the world.

Has anyone experienced something similar where customers coming from specific IP addresses/networks are experiencing SSL errors that the rest of the internet does not experience?